# Replace all other occurrences of a character range in line with the first character in the line within the range using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

A very complicated title for a very simple task (teorically at least)
I wish to write a sed script that, under a certain condition, replace all numbers with the first digit of the first number matched. So that:

12345 became 11111

I can't figure it out what I'm supposed to write in the replace section
first guess was using backrefences like this

```
s/([0-9])/\1/g
```

This match every number but, of course, replace it with the same number, because every match is distinct and the reference is on the rule not the match. How can I keep the information about the first match and us it to replace numbers further in the line?

Comment: eg 1234 abc 456 should become 1111 abc 444 >

Comment: No @Chet the first number in the line became the replace character, so that 1234 abc 456 will become 1111 abc 111

Comment: even with your clarification, your description indicates you'll be adding another qualification to your request after you see the first answer. Please learn to include required sample data (that covers all cases, as well as cases that should be unchanged) AND required output from that input.  Good luck!

Comment: I have specified that all the number in the line are replace with the first number matched, both in the title and the body. All the other detail are irrelevant they would have been included otherwise. Also I'm not interested in this particular solution, the real question here is how do you drag info about replacement traversing the line.

Comment: Looking forward to simple solution, though I myself  have a more complex one, way more code beyond one line of regexp.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a simple solution like a one line regular expression substitution.

Assumed `<>` is a sequence of characters that does not occur in your input, you could use the following short sed program

```
echo '1234 abc 456' | \
sed -e 's/\(^[^0-9]*\)\([0-9]\)/\1\2<>/g ; tLOOP bEND
  :LOOP s/\([0-9]\)<>\([^0-9]*\)[0-9]/\1\2\1<>/g; tLOOP s/<>//g ; :END'
```

Initially the marker `<>` is inserted after the first digit. If a marker has been inserted then a loop is entered (`tLOOP`) where the first digit after marker is replaced with the one before it and the marker moves through sequences of digits in a loop. Finally the markers is removed.

(The command `t` jumps to a label if the previous substitution (`s`) matched. `b` jumps unconditionally.)

If you debugged the loop (using `l0;` command after `:LOOP`) you would get the following debug output:

```
1<>234 abc 456$
11<>34 abc 456$
111<>4 abc 456$
1111<> abc 456$
1111 abc 1<>56$
1111 abc 11<>6$
1111 abc 111<>$
```

---

If you are more generally interest in *"how do you drag info about replacement traversing the line"* then you can slightly modify the above solution to make it more general, with the marker becoming a kind of "traversal context":

```
echo '1234 abc 456' | \
sed -e 's/\(^[^0-9]*\)\([0-9]\)/\1<\2>\2/g ; tLOOP bEND
  :LOOP s/<\([^>]*\)>\([^0-9]*\)[0-9]/\2\1<\1>/g; tLOOP s/<[^>]*>//g ; :END'
```

This one grabs the information (the first digit), puts it in `<>` and keeps it while moving through the line. Debugging output would be:

```
<1>1234 abc 456$
1<1>234 abc 456$
11<1>34 abc 456$
111<1>4 abc 456$
1111<1> abc 456$
1111 abc 1<1>56$
1111 abc 11<1>6$
1111 abc 111<1>$
```

The general idea is that you can use substitutions to manipulate both the pattern space and the "traversal conext" in the loop. Traversal is not limited to moving right, or by one position, etc. (You probably can e.g. implement a Turing machine this way ...)

Comment: It seems that's not the [OP wants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37632197/replace-all-other-occurrences-of-a-character-range-in-line-with-the-first-charac#comment62747279_37632197).

Comment: @Kenavoz Thank you for pointing that out. I editet my answer accordingly.

Comment: This is probably the best approach, since it use sed only. I was thinking about using characters to pinpoint what needs to be copied, still it's a bit too complicated for the level of programming that should be necessary to solve it. Maybe the fault is in the exercise text. Thank you anyway it was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk:

```
$ echo '1234 abc 456' | awk '{gsub(/[0-9]/,substr($0,1,1))} 1'
1111 abc 111
```

or if your line can start with a non-digit:

```
$ echo 'foo 1234 abc 456' | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]/){gsub(/[0-9]/,substr($0,RSTART,1))} 1'
foo 1111 abc 111
```

which with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` is slightly briefer:

```
$ echo 'foo 1234 abc 456' | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]/,d){gsub(/[0-9]/,d[0])} 1'
foo 1111 abc 111
```

If you want to give yourself a headache figuring out what a match() within a substr() within a gsub() does, you could also write:

```
$ echo 'foo 1234 abc 456' | awk '{gsub(/[0-9]/,substr($0,match($0,/[0-9]/),1))} 1'
foo 1111 abc 111
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]/\n/2g;:a;s/(([0-9]).*)\n/\1\2/;ta' file
```

This replaces all but the first digit with newlines (a character that by seds definition can not exist in an unadulterated line). It then uses a loop to work backwards through the file replacing each newline with the only digit found in the line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable with GNU Awk, here is such a script:

**script.awk**

```
{ if( match( $0, /^[^0-9]*([0-9])/, inf ) ) {
    $0=gensub( /[0-9]/, inf[1], "g")
  }
  print $0
}
```

Use it like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`

- it tries to match the first digit of each line with the `match` function,
- the actual string matched by the part inside the first parentesis is saved inside `inf[1]`
- then all digits in the line are replaced by the digit in `inf[1]` using the `gensub` function

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, I wanted to change from `[[:digit:]]` to the shorter `[0-9]` and forget to remove the double brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '1234 abc 456' | awk '{gsub(/234|456/,"111")}1'
1111 abc 111
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this came up on the low quality post review queue. Please edit your post to include an explanation of what is occurring for future folks that stumble across the question. Cheers ~